# Using the PHP _FILES global in conjunction with App Inventor

Tags: php, android, post, app-inventor

I'm trying to post an image to a PHP page using MIT's Android App Inventor. I need to verify the mime type before I save the image to my server, which I chose to use `$_FILES` in PHP with  POST. However, App Inventor does not seem to support sending POST variables and instead sends the file as the request body.

Can I, and if so, how can I use App Inventor to post an image/file to my PHP page using PHP's `$_FILES`? If not, how can I work around this with the ability to verify that the sent file is really an image?

Currently, I'm using the following criteria for mime types:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10485760)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
        //Do stuff and save the file
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I, and if so, how can I use App Inventor to post an image/file to
>   my PHP page using PHP's `$_FILES`?

I don't think so

> If not, how can I work around this with the ability to verify that
>   the sent file is really an image?

[see this solution](http://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php), you can pass the mime type as parameter (same as strACCESSKEY in the example)

[image]